# Xamarin + Android + Binding YouTube video player compile errors

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, youtube

I'm looking to bind the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar into my Xamarin Android project.  I've added the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar under my Jars folder, but my project won't compile.

Error: "Do not override object.Finalize.  Instead use a destructor."

So I've tried to change the way it compiles by using an:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='Com.Google.Android.Youtube.Player']/class[@name='YouTubeThumbnailView']/method[@name='Finalize']" name="managedName">~YouTubeThumbnailView</attr>
```

In the Metadata.xml file under Transforms folder...  It doesn't seem to change it to a finalizer though...  I'm continuing to play around with the syntax here in hopes that I stumble across something that works.

Is this the right approach?  Is there something else I could be doing that is a better solution?  I'd really like some feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to remove this fairly easily. However your issue in your `<attr>` is the fact that you have the incorrect package name/class name as it should follow Java convention(`<lowercase package>.<propercase class>`). Simply ensure the case like the example below:

**EX:**

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/class[@name='YouTubeThumbnailView']/method[@name='finalize' and count(parameter)=0]" />
```

Comment: I think I'm on my way now, thank you!  I did have some case sensitivity issues.  Thanks for helping on this!!!

Comment: Please see my binding guide if you encounter any further issues! https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: thanks!  I've added it to my favorites.  Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @JonDouglas Hello.. I am having the same issue in my bindings as well. I tried with both the cases and I am getting the same error. I tried remove-node as well and it is throwing error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  "javadoc-to-mdoc.exe" exited with code 1.

Comment: Open up a new question, that error message is saying something entirely different!

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `remove-node`, you will remove the `finalizer` and the code under `finalize` method will never be called.
If you want to re-use the `finalize` implementation in the destructor, you can add the following to your `Metadata.xml` file:

```xml
<!--  
    YouTubeThumbnailView class implemented a Java Finalizer. I have to implement a C# Destructor and call the finalize method.
    The C# Destructor is in the partial class under the Addition folder.
-->
<!-- I change the name of the finalizer method to avoid the conflict with java finalizer -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/class[@name='YouTubeThumbnailView']/method[@name='finalize' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedName">InternalFinalize</attr>
<!-- I replace the protected override modifier with the internal modifier -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/class[@name='YouTubeThumbnailView']/method[@name='finalize' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">internal</attr>
```

**N.B.** the visibility modifier is needed to remove the `override` modifier.

Then you should add the following class under the folder `Additions`:

```cs
namespace Com.Google.Android.Youtube.Player
{
    public partial class YouTubeThumbnailView
    {
        ~YouTubeThumbnailView()
        {
            this.InternalFinalize();
        }
    }
}
```