# Xamarin.Android binding generations for Finalizer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is there a proper way to work with finalizers to generate proper `xamarin.android` bindings?

I have original aar lib which is compiled with `API level 24`. This lib is added to the `xamarin.android` binding library project. Xamarin targets JDK8 in preferences `jdk1.8.0_91`.

The original code has `protected void finalize()` method, so the generated code looks like this: `protected override unsafe void Finalize ()`

which cause the following error: `"Do not override object.Finalize. Instead, provide a destructor."`

Are there any suggestions how to omit this, except cut that finalize method from generation on the xamarin side with the `<remove-node>` tag in `Metadata.xml`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin + Android + Binding YouTube video player compile errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290706/xamarin-android-binding-youtube-video-player-compile-errors)

Comment: Just `<remove-node>` them....

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `remove-node`, you will remove the `finalizer` and the code under `finalize` method will never be called.
If you want to re-use the `finalize` implementation in the destructor, you can add the following to your `Metadata.xml` file:

```xml
<!--  
    ClassName class implemented a Java Finalizer. I have to implement a C# Destructor and call the finalize method.
    The C# Destructor is in the partial class under the Addition folder.
-->
<!-- I change the name of the finalizer method to avoid the conflict with java finalizer -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='your.package.name']/class[@name='ClassName']/method[@name='finalize' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedName">InternalFinalize</attr>
<!-- I replace the protected override modifier with the internal modifier -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='your.package.name']/class[@name='ClassName']/method[@name='finalize' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">internal</attr>
```

**N.B.** the visibility modifier is needed to remove the `override` modifier.

Then you should add the following class under the folder `Additions`:

```cs
namespace Your.Package.Name
{
    public partial class ClassName
    {
        ~ClassName()
        {
            this.InternalFinalize();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply remove the `finalize` method via the following:

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='your.package.name']/class[@name='Proper.ClassName']/method[@name='finalize' and count(parameter)=0]" />
```